# Select entries that contain information about smartphones among other data

Tags: java, dataset, data-science

I'm not sure on how to approach the following problem, and I'm looking for some guidance:

I have a File which contains an random Ad Title on each line. What I need to do is to classify each title in **smartphone** or **not-smartphone**, depending if the Ad is selling a mobile phone or not.

I'm sorry the file isn't in english, but here is a screenshot showing a little bit of it:
[complete file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MST7K.png)
[image]

**Problems I've encountered:**

- Some Ad titles are related to smartphones, but they aren't actually selling  phones, but something related to it (acessory). Example: an ad selling phone cases for Iphone X
- Some ad titles doesn't even have the phone brand, but only the model. Example: "White Xiaomi Mi Mix 2s Global 64GB" or "J7 Pro 64gb 4g J730".
- It would be perfect if there was a way to extract the exact phone model from the title, but since each ad title is formatted differently, I couldn't find a way to do this.
- Usually brands produce a variety of products, and smartphones are just one type of product. So when I filter by the brand name, it often returns me ads which aren't related to smartphones at all (tablets, TVs, chargers, etc). More filtering would be needed
- Even though I am allowed to use it, I couldn't find some DB with a list of all smartphone models, or I don't know how to retrieve information from them.

**What I've thought so far:**

- if I had access to a DataBase with a big quantity of smartphone models, I could directly search the file for each model name (example; "Iphone 5s" or "Moto G6").
- I tried using FonoAPI https://fonoapi.freshpixl.com (which is a smartphone database for consulting data about the phones using java,php, etc) to search for smartphone models from a specific brand, but the api will only return a max of 100 results per time. So in order to use it, I would need to **extract the product model name** from the title so I can check if it is listed in the FonoAPI DB

So since each ad title in the file is formatted differently, I'm looking for some ideas on how to do this, because I couldn't find a way to extract the product model from the title to compare with FonoAPI database, neither get access to some big DB containing a vast quantity of models to directly look for them in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not very precise and more like ideas i wanted to propose (because i like this problem and would be happy to get the file, seems like it is impossible to get it from your link).

First, as all NLP problems you need to ensure all the text is formatted the same way.

To get a phone model database. I would try to get a database with phone brands. Then go on a selling website to do web scraping. This way you would get a lot of phone model.

I would try to use some NLP model like LDA, but with another formatted way (like getting away the words beyond a limit after gb and the phone brands. We can hope all the phone are close to those words).

This can be stupid ideas, but i wanted to share (and i can not comment :D).